# Switch Microphone settings to Hardware Processing

Tags: c#, vb.net

So i asked a question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167058/play-recording-into-microphone-in-real-time-for-voip

But no one apparently knew what I was looking for? So im going to try to go at this a different way. There is a way to switch your microphone/sound settings to "hardware processing" so your output plays whatever music/sound you are listening through from your speakers/headset...

How do you do this method "Programatically" ? Like I want to be able to do this in a vb.net/c# program by pressing a button to toggle it on and off.

One of the people that responded linked this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fu371l4lFjk
Which is EXACTLY what i want to do, BUT i want to be able to do this programatically and very easily.

Make sense?

Comment: You'll have to use the WASAPI api to do this.  It has lots of sharp edges, it is a COM interface without automation support so its hard to directly use from C#.  Documentation is sparse as well.  A random google hit that looked good is [this wrapper](http://www.multimediasoft.com/asrecnet/help/index.html?how_to_wasapi.htm).

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11695/Audio-Library-Part-I-Windows-Mixer-Control

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the [NAudio Library](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) and then specifically at [this question](http://naudio.codeplex.com/discussions/82012) to do what I think you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [another wrapper](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18520/Vista-Core-Audio-API-Master-Volume-Control) for the Audio api's which should do what you want.